# Offset in custom font's vertical alignment

Tags: android, html, ios, css, fonts

Lately I've encountered one specific problem with custom fonts for multiple times. No matter whether I've programmed for iOS, Android or the web - the problem has always occurred.

The vertical alignment of fonts. Let's have a look at an example:
[image: example]

Working with any sort of padding works, but it's bad considering that the app has to be responsive.

So how can I remove this space/distance below the font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with custom fonts is that they often have a ascender/descender.

In this case, the descender causes the issue. To solve it, we have to edit the font itself.

**How can we do so?** 
There are several tools to edit your fonts. Since I'm working on a Mac, I'm using the [Apple Font Tool Suite](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/). Once you’ve installed this you need to open Terminal and navigate to the directory that contains your font. After that enter the following command:

> ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf

This will create a file called font.hhea.xml, open this new file into a text editor and adjust the values for the descender. After editing and saving enter the following command into terminal to reconstruct your Font file:

> ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf

**Note that there are three different sets of vertical metrics in most fonts.** In the OS/2 table under metrics: (1) the WinAscent, WinDescent, (2) TypoAscender, TypoDescender, and (3) in the hhea table: the Ascender, Descender and LineGap.

The commands would be:

> ftxdumperfuser -t OS/2 -A d font.ttf - when finished editing: ftxdumperfuser -t OS/2 -A f font.ttf

Solely changing the descender in the hhea table will change the font for any Apple device, but not for a Windows devices. Hence it's always recommended to change all three ascenders/descender (especially hhea and TypoAscender/TypoDescender).

In case you happen to work on another operating system. Just get any tool to edit fonts and edit the given values.